# Where is the error in this apparent contradiction arising from the function $f(\pm n)=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\pm 1}$?

Tags: fractions

We define a function $ f \left( \pm n \right) =\left( \frac{ n }{ n + 1 } \right) ^ { \pm 1 } $.
That is, $$ f \left( m \right) = \begin{cases}\frac{ m }{ m + 1 } &\text{ if } m \ge 0 \\ \frac{ -m + 1 }{ -m } & \text{ if }m \lt 0 \end{cases}. $$

From this, $ f \left( - a \right) = \frac{ a + 1 }{ a } = \frac{ a }{ a } + \frac{ 1 }{ a }= 1 + \frac{ 1 }{ a } $

However, we can also do this:
$ f \left( \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta } > 0 \right) = \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta } \div \left( \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta } + 1 \right) = \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta } \div \left( \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta } + \frac{ \beta }{ \beta } \right) = \\ = \frac{ \alpha }{ \beta } \div \frac{ \alpha + \beta }{ \beta } = \frac{ \alpha \beta }{ \alpha \beta + \beta ^ 2 } $

Since $ \frac{ \alpha \beta + \beta ^ 2 }{ \alpha \beta } = 1 + \frac{ \beta ^ 2 }{ \alpha \beta } = 1 + \frac{ \beta }{ \alpha } = \frac{ \alpha + \beta }{ \alpha } $, $ \frac{ \alpha \beta }{ \alpha \beta + \beta ^ 2 } =  \frac{ \alpha }{ \alpha + \beta } $.

Since $ f \left( k \right) = \frac{ 1 }{ f \left( - k \right)} $, $ f \left( - \frac{ \gamma }{ \delta } \right) = \frac{ \gamma }{ \gamma + \delta } $.

But this conflicts with the previous definition!
It says that $f \left( -2 \right) = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }$ AND $= 1 + \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }$!

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is wrong: $f\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\right)=\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}$. In fact:

$$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}=f\left(\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\right)=\frac{1}{f\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\right)}$$
hence
$$f\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\right)=\frac{\gamma+\delta}{\gamma}.$$
So $$f(-2)=f\left(-\frac{2}{1}\right)=\frac{3}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I understand, but where is the wrong step in my transformations?

Comment: The problem is in the sentence: 
Since $ f \left( k \right) = \frac{ 1 }{ f \left( - k \right)} $, $ f \left( - \frac{ \gamma }{ \delta } \right) = \frac{ \gamma }{ \gamma + \delta } $. You take the wrong value for either $f(-\frac{\gamma}{\delta})$ or $f(\frac{\gamma}{\delta})$ (you did not fully work out that step so I'm not sure what your thinking process was.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this, I marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you have , where you used alpha and beta

$\frac{a}{b}\div \frac{a + b}{b} = \frac{a}{a +b}$

but you've ended up with $b^2$ etc which is right, but you could cancel b

then you say 'since' and you don't cancel b out properly

Comment: How could I cancel there? $\frac{a}{a + b} \neq \frac{1}{b}$ or anything like that AFAIK.